# API call json_decode() creating object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from an simple API, simply returning odds & sports among a couple of other strings.

Im specifically looking for the `$result['sport'] variable.

Im playing around with the following code but I repeatedly get back an error

> Call of object property on none object type.

As I understand it `json_decode()` returns type object, which is seems confirmed when doing a `var_dump()`?

The below code returns the following

[image]

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.the-odds-api.com/v2/sports/?apiKey=123456789'); 

$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj);
$urlData = array();
foreach ($obj as $value) {
    $urlData[] = $value->$urlData; //Trying to get property of non-object in
    echo $value['sport']; //Undefined index: sport 
    echo $value->$urlData; //Trying to get property of non-object
}
print_r($urlData) //Array ([0]=>[1]=>)
```

Any advice above, appreciated!

Comment: Set json_decode()'s second parameter to TRUE, and everything is put into an array instead, making it easier for some people.

Comment: Hi Brian I have tried that `$obj = json_decode($json, true); foreach ($obj as $value) { echo $value['sport']; }` however I get back an undefined index error when trying to access

Answer (score 1):

To get `json_decode` to return an array use `json_decode($json, true);`. Then access items in array.

Update

Try

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true); 
foreach ($obj['data'] as $value) { 
    echo $value['display_name']; 
}
```

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json, true);`  `foreach ($obj as $value) {
    echo $value['sport'];
}` results in undefined index error

Comment: Thanks that worked.  May I ask where does the `$obj['data']` in foreach() loop comes from?

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_decode($json, true);  When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.